# ES6: Constructor's parameter has been changed before explicitly used

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the below code, the `ParentClass` class receives the argument from `ChildClass` (in the real project, `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` are in separate files, and `CSS_CLASSES` is declared in `ChildClass` file).

```
class ParentClass {

    constructor(CSS_CLASSES, mode){ 

        if (mode === 'call getCssClassesSelectors') {

            this.CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS = ParentClass.getCssClassesSelectors(CSS_CLASSES);    

        }
        else if (mode === 'dont call getCssClassesSelectors'){
            console.log(CSS_CLASSES);   
        }
    }

    static getCssClassesSelectors(CSS_CLASSES) {

        let outputObjectWorkpiece = Object.assign({}, CSS_CLASSES);

        // local same-name function 
        function getCssClassesSelectors(outputObjectWorkpiece){
            for (let key in outputObjectWorkpiece){

                if (outputObjectWorkpiece.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                    if (typeof(outputObjectWorkpiece[key]) === 'string') {
                        outputObjectWorkpiece[key] = '.' + outputObjectWorkpiece[key];
                    }
                    else if (typeof(outputObjectWorkpiece[key]) === 'object'){
                        getCssClassesSelectors(outputObjectWorkpiece[key]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return outputObjectWorkpiece;
        }

        return getCssClassesSelectors(outputObjectWorkpiece);

    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass { 

    constructor() {   
        super(CSS_CLASSES, 'call getCssClassesSelectors');

    } 
}

let CSS_CLASSES = {
    pageWrapper: 'pageWrapper',
    header: {
        wrapper: 'header-wrapper',
        logo: 'header-logo'
    },
    signInForm: {
        wrapper: 'main-innerWrapper',
        inputField: 'signInForm-inputField',
        button: 'signInForm-inputField'
    }
};

let testInstance = new ChildClass();
```

`CSS_CLASS` is the object with obviously contains css classes in unknown in advance nesting levels. The parent class must to convert all classes to CSS selectors, more concretely, add `'.'` to each `CSS_CLASSES` property in all nesting levels.

I added the `mode` parameter to demonstrate the problem.

### Problem

If we call `this.ccs = Resource.getCssClassesSelectors(CSS_CLASSES)`, the `CSS_CLASSES` in the previous row already becomes to selectors (`'.'` will we added to each property):

```
 if (mode === 'call getCssClassesSelectors') {

    console.log(CSS_CLASSES);
    // all properties already becomes to selectors!!! But how?

    this.ccs = ParentClass.getCssClassesSelectors(CSS_CLASSES);  

}
```

I tried the next fiddle:

```
let parent = { a: 1 };
let child = Object.assign({}, parent);
child.a = 2;

console.log(parent); // { a : 1}
console.log(child); // { a : 2}
```

Now problem: the child is independent. So here in my case the problem has another origin...

Comment: You're only creating a *shallow* copy of the object, all the nested objects within it aren't copied.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In the one of answer on "What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?" it was told that `Object.assign({}, obj);` is the deep copy. Where is the logic error?

Comment: *Which* answer says that `Object.assign` creates a deep copy?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188775/4818123),  clause 1; has 32 upvotes.

Comment: Look at the comments to that answer…

Comment: Indeed! So, the concisest method is `jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);`, is't it?

Comment: *If* you're already using jQuery… I suppose.

Comment: OK, than you for the guidance to answer!